# Shell script menu option

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to create a script with different menu options. One of them is to create a file containing

1. who is logged in
2. disk usage
3. running processes

The file should be date stamped and saved to a directory.

I'm new to Linux so I'm trying to figure this out. So far I know that to stamp a file I can use `(date"+%Y.%m.%d")`, to show who is logged in I can use the `who` command, to show disk space is `df -h`, running processes `ps -aux` and to create a file is `touch`.

How do I put these together to create this menu option?

Update:

This is what i created and it works! However it doesn't save to the log_dir directory. It just saves it to home directory

```
filename=log_file-$(date +%Y.%m.%d) 
touch $filename 
{ who; df -h; ps -aux; } > $HOME/$log_dir/$filename
```

I tried a different option like this but i gives me an error message "permission denied"

```
filename=log_file-$(date +%Y.%m.%d) 
touch $filename 
{ who; df -h; ps -aux; } > $log_dir/$filename
```

What's going wrong?

Thank you for all the help! Much appreciated

Comment: what do you mean by different menu option?

Comment: so google "menu bash" and for sure you'll get some examples. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1705/how-can-i-create-a-select-menu-in-a-shell-script is my first google hit, https://devdojo.com/bobbyiliev/how-to-create-an-interactive-menu-in-bash is my second. If you want to create a real TUI use `whiptail` or `dialog`.

Comment: I have already created a menu with a few options for the users to pick from. I'm stuck on this particular menu option which should allow the user to create a file that contains log details, disk usage and running procesesses. I'm not sure how to implement this and i would really appreciate some help! Thank you

Comment: `who > output-$(date +%Y.%m.%d)` puts the output of `who` in the file.

Comment: That worked, thank you! how do i add disk space and runninng processor in the file too?

Comment: @user15387538 Don’t edit the question into a completely different question. If you have another question then post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

In general, to create a new file with the output of a command, you redirect with `>`.  So `cmd > path` puts the output of `cmd` into `path`.  To add the output of multiple commands into a file, you have several options.  Two commonly used approaches are:

```
{ who; df -h; ps -aux; } > /p/a/t/h-$(date +%Y.%m.%d)
```

or:

```
output=output-$(date +%Y.%m.%d)
who > "$output"
df -h >> "$output"
ps -aux >> "$output"
```

A third popular choice is to use `exec` to redirect all output of the script to the file.  For example:

```
exec > output-file
who
df -h
ps -aux
```

This cause *all* output of the script to go to the output-file unless redirected again, and this sometimes causes some confusion.  It is easy to save/restore the output, and you will often see:

```
exec 3>&1 > output
cmd
cmd2
exec >&3
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the function you called for that menu option:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Creating `newFile` using touch command 
fileName=newFile-$(date +%Y.%m.%d)
touch $fileName

# Who is logged in 
# Double gt in line 9 means appending the output at the end of the file
echo "-------Who is logged in----------" >> $fileName
echo "$(who)" >> $fileName

# Disk usage
echo "-------Disk Usage----------" >> $fileName
echo "$(df -h)" >> $fileName

# Running processes
echo "-------Running Processes----------" >> $fileName
echo "$(ps -aux)" >> $fileName
```